# What is an intersection matrix and how it works?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

At [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_intro.htm#i879003) there is a doc about how to handle spatial coordinates and shapes, the figure shows an *intersection matrix* and according to the writer this matrix generates a bit pattern.

\begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1
 \end{matrix}

I don't understand what are the inputs ( vectors ? scalars ? ) , how this matrix works ( I'm supposed to add, multiply, ... ? this matrix with something else ) and what kind of mapping is that assuming that is linear mapping.

Does this matrix really exist or is an exotic adaptation of a concept that has a different name in math ?

Comment: Here's [more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) about what's going on. I've never seen this before, but I strongly suspect it's merely a way to *store* information (a table of numbers), rather than an algebraic object. That is, I don't *think* you add these together, or let them act on vectors, it seems to just be a way store (topological) information.

Comment: @pjs36 thanks, I think that this goes in the right direction, so it's a way to annotate geometrical properties, I still don't get how it works since we are talking about shapes like widgets for a GUI that can be moved so that matrix is supposed to change at every step of the way if I understood that correctly . For example does this notation comes with a dedicated algorithm ?

Comment: a practical example about how you detect even just one of those properties could be really helpful